# C++ System(); function not working as expected / Windows console commands in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, windows-console, avrdude

Hello friendly people of stack overflow!

I am currently working on a project using an Arduino Uno. Because i create all my files and sketches using a c++ program, i want to eliminate the Arduino IDE from my workflow. For that i can very easily use avrdude (which the IDE uses anyway) and some windows console commands.
These are the commands that i am using:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Jzargo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_766345/EPaper_TestDither.ino.hex:i

"EPaper_TestDither.ino" is the arduino Sketch i want to compile and upload. When using the console and manually inserting the above commands, everything works as expected.

And here comes the part I am struggeling with:

Because i also dont want the user to manually open the console and type in some gibberish code, i want to integrate this command into my c++ program using the system(); function:

```
system("\"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avrdude\" \" - CC:\\Program Files(x86)\\Arduino\\\hardware\\tools\\avr/etc/avrdude.conf\" -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\\Users\\Jzargo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_766345/EPaper_TestDither.ino.hex:i");
```

When executing this function, the command cannot be executed because "Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.", which roughly translates to "The Command "C:\Program" is not written correctly or cant be found".

I do not understand why the console accepts the command when manually inserting it, but not when using the system(); function.

I hope you can help me figure this out.

*Edit:* By using
`subst H: "C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin"` and

```
system("\"H:/avrdude \"-CC:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf\"\" -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:/Users/Jzargo/AppData/Local/Temp/arduino_build_833906/EPaper_TestDither.ino.hex:i");
```

I was able to upload my sketch. Note the changed Placement of `\"`.

But for some reason, this does not work when using `C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin` instead of `H:`.

Kindest regards

J'zargo

Comment: This is always due to incorrect quoting/spacing/escaping. You need to understand: 1) how your operating system shell parses commands, 2) how `system` executes the given command, 3) how literal character strings need to be escaped in order to represent special characters. Your question is somewhat garbled, and it's hard to see exactly what your code looks like. In any case, you should be able to find all of the above information in your textbook. Is there something specific on this topic, in your textbook, that's unclear to you?

Comment: Ha, I just ranted about the Windows way of passing arguments [here](https://superuser.com/a/1641129/316104). How fitting.

Comment: Hello Sam, thank you for your answer.
Sorry for the garbling of my question, i am new to this forum.
I am not working of of a textbook. The way I understand the System(); function in c++ is that it just calls the host environment's command processor with the given command (the console in my case). So i thought that any command that works when inserting it directly in the console should also work with system(); as long as you make sure the string is formatted correctly. But i figured that this assumption is wrong (otherwise it would work). I will comment my code without extra backslashes:

Comment: @sam-varshavchik i tried to use some of the formatting features to make the question less garbled

Comment: @peter-reinstate-monica well, fitting indeed. But i have to be honest that i barely understand your comment because of my lack of knowledge about, well, windows, i guess... So i dont really know how this can help me fix my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command looks messed up with respect to the parameters, although I don't see how exactly that triggers your specific error.

The beginning is OK. The path is properly quoted (double quotes, protected by backslashes from the C compiler). But why do you have slashes and backslashes mixed? In some online examples I saw that people use forward slashes in Windows paths (`C:/whatever...`) ; that seems to work and is easier than using double backslashes all the time (but it should not trigger your — or any — error).

So `system("\"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avrdude\" ...` should call the right executable. Why don't you try that *on its own* (without parameters) to see whether the error persists?

I suspect that `\" - CC:\\Program Files(x86)\\ ...` is not correct though. avrdude expects a parameter `-C<path>`, not  `- C<path>` (note the badly placed spaces before and after the dash).

As an aside, it may not hurt to quote parameters that contain funny characters like colons which may have special meanings.

The general advice for this kind of trouble:

- Work in and with paths that do not contain spaces, brackets, or other non-identifier characters. If you don't want to change the avrdude installation path you can use the DOS `subst` command to create a drive whose root is `C:\Program Files(x86)` or even `C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin`, e.g. `subst H: "C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin"`. The command would then be `H:/avrdude` :-).
- If confronted with a bug you don't understand, simplify the problem radically until a toy version works; then add complexity bit by bit until you encounter the error; that should make it easier to recognize what triggered it.

Edit: I'm not sure this example is valid because I used the msys2 development environment and ran the example in a bash shell; I'm not even sure `cmd` is called as the system shell by the `syste` call!

<strike>In order to check the system call semantics I wrote the following minimal example (which uses mixed slashes/backslashes as a test). The current directory has a sub directory called "some dir" containing a minimal program `showargs` which simply writes its command line parameters to stdout:</strike>

```
$ ls -l "some dir" && echo && cat cmdline.c && echo && gcc -o cmdline cmdline.c && ./cmdline.exe
total 56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Peter None 56097 Apr 16 17:23 showargs.exe

#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        system("\".\\some dir/showargs\" 1 2 3");
}

->.\some dir/showargs<-
->1<-
->2<-
->3<-
```

Comment: @peter-reinstate-monica: Hey Peter, thanks for the help! Somehow, this worked. By using `subst H: "C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin"` and `system("\"H:/avrdude \"-CC:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf\"\" -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:/Users/Lennart/AppData/Local/Temp/arduino_build_833906/EPaper_TestDither.ino.hex:i");` I was able to upload my sketch. But for some reason, this does not work when using `C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin` instead of `H:`

Comment: Also i am not entirely sure why i needed to place the ´"´ the way I did for it to work. And why does it work with H:/ but not with the path in C:/ i honestly dont get it. Remove the "H:/" and insert it's root and it stops working.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I have investigated a bit further and found that `system("showargs 1 \"2 3\"");` works while `system("\"showargs\" 1 \"2 3\"");` (extra quotes around the program name) does not The error message is `'showargs" 1 "2' is not recognized as...`, indicating that the first escaped double quote is swallowed so that the second one is taken as the *start* of a quoted string and concatenated with what comes before and after it. If the path has a space the "word" ends there. That resembles your use case.-- Good that you got it to work!

Comment: @peter-reinstate-monica again, thanks a lot! I'm glad i got it to work, even though i'd prefer to not need the workaround with H:/ but maybe i'll figure this one out, i'll definetely try to change the syntax some more.  Theoretically i'd also need to compile the sketch without the IDE but I have to concede that that's too much to handle for my mechanical-engineer-brain, at least for now! 
Ich wünsche Ihnen in jeden Fall ein schönes Wochenende!